# Indexing this sql query for best optimisation

Tags: mysql, optimization

In an existing project, I have a db in phpmyadmin, the database is supposed to hold a large amount of data in the long run. i will frequently need to draw yearly reports for customers, when i draw a report with the total record in database was around 950,000 the search time was around 15 seconds which was quite satisfying so far, however when i inserted 400,000 more test data in the database the search time jumped from 15 sec to a frustrating time of 2.08 mins.
I tried to run defragment and optimise in operation without any diference in the time.

I noticed the table is not indexed ( as it should have been according to some Google searches ) i would like an advice on how to best index the tables as I am new to indexing.

Here is the query.

```
            $currentuserid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
$year='2008';
            $query = $this->db->query("     
select  customers.id,customers.customername,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 1,  keyslog.count, 0 )) as January,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 2,  keyslog.count, 0 )) as February,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 3,  keyslog.count, 0 )) as March,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 4,  keyslog.count, 0 )) as April,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 5,  keyslog.count, 0 )) as May,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 6,  keyslog.count, 0 )) as June,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 7,  keyslog.count, 0 )) as July,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 8,  keyslog.count, 0 )) as August,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 9,  keyslog.count, 0 )) as September,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 10, keyslog.count, 0 )) as October,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 11, keyslog.count, 0 )) as November,
      sum(if( MONTH(keyslog.timestamp) = 12, keyslog.count, 0 )) as December,
      sum(keyslog.count) as Total
    from  customers, keyslog, users_customer
    where  (YEAR(timestamp) = '$year')
      AND  customers.id = keyslog.customers
      AND  users_customer.custo_id = keyslog.customers
      AND  keyslog.active = '1'
      AND  users_customer.userID = '$currentuserid'
      AND  users_customer.checked='1'
    group by  customers.id,customers.customername
```

As advised I tried to run explain and here is the result however I cant interpret it

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  keyslog     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1437493     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  customers   eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY     4   iccid.keyslog.customers     1   
1   SIMPLE  users_customer  ref     userID,checked,userID_2     userID_2    12  const,iccid.customers.id,const  1   Using where; Using index
```

Any suggestion on how to add any indexes on which tables or how to change the query to reach the best optimal retrieval would be much appreciated

Should I also specifically target the indexes that i add in the query 
for example

```
from customers,keyslog,users_customer USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ?
```

Comment: In addition to the EXPLAIN please provide the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE for all the relevant tables

Comment: is keyslog.customers an int type field and is it indexed and is users_customer.userID indexed and if timestamp field in condition is doing much data filteration if yes then is it indexed...you also need to remove year(timestamp) function to use its index if data is filtering based on this condition....

Comment: hello strawberry i am not able to run show create table as the table is already craeted is there an alternative?

Comment: zafar yes keyslog.customer is an int type but is not indexed. users_customer.userID is indexed. the time stamp is doing filtration. if i remove the Year i dont know how to get the equivalent of this query as it will not give the yearly report by months isnt it?

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table

Comment: with that i get only a part of the table for example Show create table users_customer gives an incomplete answer terminated by three dots (...) users_customer  CREATE TABLE `users_customer` (
 `id` int(12) NOT...

Comment: What tool are you using?  phpmyadmin, workbench, mysql commandline -- all have a way to type in `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

users_customer: `INDEX(userID, checked)` -- unless `userID` is the `PRIMARY KEY`
keyslog: `INDEX(customers)`
customers:  `INDEX(id)` -- unless it is already `PRIMARY KEY`.

Instead of `(YEAR(timestamp) = '$year')`, use

```
timestamp >= '$year-01-01'  AND
timestamp  < '$year-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

(The optimizer is not smart enough to do the obvious thing with `YEAR()`.)

For clarity, switch to the `JOIN...ON` syntax.

Learn about summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables